# Should Wrap be on all these CSS classes, or should Nav be on all of them?

Tags: html, css

I have a question if someone can help me with this.

Should **Wrap** be on all these classes, or should **Nav** be on all of them?

**or Should both be used?**

Which would you say to use, and why?

Click on the Image to see the Links

**1st Way**

https://jsfiddle.net/jq18evLs/137/

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="covere" title="OPEN"></div>
  <div class="nav">
```

---

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 266px;
  height: 174px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap a {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 4px 12px 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap a:hover {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.wrap a:nth-of-type(5n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.wrap a:nth-of-type(8) {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.wrap a:nth-of-type(15) {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
}
```

}

Click on the Image to see the Links

**2nd Way**

https://jsfiddle.net/jq18evLs/139/

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="covere" title="OPEN"></div>
  <div class="nav">
```

---

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 266px;
  height: 174px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 4px 12px 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav a:hover {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.nav a:nth-of-type(5n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav a:nth-of-type(8) {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.nav a:nth-of-type(15) {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
}
```

Click on the Image to see the Links

**3rd Way**

https://jsfiddle.net/jq18evLs/143/

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="covere" title="OPEN"></div>
  <div>

------------------------------------

  .wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 266px;
  height: 174px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

  .wrap a {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 4px 12px 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap a:hover {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.wrap a:nth-of-type(5n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.wrap a:nth-of-type(8) {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.wrap a:nth-of-type(15) {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap a {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what the differences are, because it's not very clear from the fiddles alone.

Comment: @MrLister If you were writing the code. Which would have .Wrap on them, Which would have .Nav on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Based on the HTML in your question, I'll go with option 2. Why? Because it works and the selectors are not over qualifying. For example, say an HTML page contains two kinds of anchor links - first that link to within the website (same domain) and others that lead to external websites. And your HTML looks like the following:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="internal-links">
    <a href="/1.html"></a>
    <a href="/2.html"></a>
    <a href="/3.html"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="external-links">
    <a href="https://google.com/1.html"></a>
    <a href="https://google.com/2.html"></a>
    <a href="https://google.com/3.html"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I will style the anchor tags in the above HTML like the following:

```
.internal-links a {
  color: blue;
}

.external-links a {
  color: red;
}
```

But if all the links had to be styled in the same way then I would just do:

```
a {
    color: blue;
}
```

I think making the decision about nesting classes or selectors depends upon 2 things:

**1. Specificity** - Specificity is how browsers decide which CSS rule to apply to a given element. Read more about specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

**2. CSS management** - Bigger projects may require some kind of strategy to keep the CSS manageable. Or sometimes nesting selectors might just make sense. Take the following code for example:

```
button.large {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

img.large {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Now here using the `img` or `button` selectors make total sense. This example uses additional selectors to account for variants. Similarly, the same solution can be applied to manage state `a.is-active`.